# proctoring phrases

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I work as an exam proctor and I want to ask what are the correct structure of the the following phrases and sentences:

1. all the notes are outside and make.sure your phone is closed and outside in your bag or on my table
2. it's half the time now. 1hr is left
3. half time is left.
4. 30 minutes are left
5. stay on your paper and don't talk or look aside!

Please correct me and recommend other common phrases.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Leave your notes outside and make sure your phone is off and outside in your bag, or on my table.
2. The exam is halfway through.  You have one hour left.
3. Half the time has gone.
4. 30 minutes are left <- fine as it is.
5. Keep your eyes on your own paper.  No talking and no looking at other papers.

Also, not a phrase, but I recommend you use a visual to show time passed/remaining.  For example, draw a line with four evenly spaced marks to indicate one quarter of the exam.  As each quarter passes, erase or cross out that length of the line.